# Search List of a type for exact variable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, search

I want to create a function that would search a list for something and return bool.

MyList has multiple elements inside. Each has a variable **name** assigned different string. I want to search the list for a particular **name**.
Example:

```
public class Type 
{
    public string name;
}

List<Type> MyList;

bool FindByName(string str) 
{
    foreach (Type type in MyList) 
    {
        if (type.name == str) 
            return true;
    }
}
```

The FindByName function is what I would like to make universal. A function that would take:

```
List<T>, NameOfVariableToLookIn, U WhatToLookFor
```

And you could just give the function:

```
List<Type>, name, string str
```

Worried if this is even possible. I really don't want to write a new function for each new list I create.

Comment: Have you heard of Linq?  Specifically `.Any()`?  Its as simple as: `bool isFound = myList.Any(name == someString);`

Comment: What you are looking for is an Extension methods to List type. See - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `Any()` extension method from `System.Linq` namespace. And you could implement an extension method. For sample:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool FindByName(this IEnumerable<Type> list, string str)
    {
        return list.Any(x => x.name == str);
    }
}
```

Remember, an extension method is a static method instead and not part of the list so you should  reference `Extensions` class. You could use it like this:

```
List<Type> MyList = new List<Type>();
MyList.Add(..); // add objects

var exists = MyList.FindByName("john");
```

Comment: An overload with `StringComparison` or `StringComparer` would be nice

Comment: This is more then enough for me. Thank you a lot.